# Deleting records in sales cloud using REST api

Tags: api, rest, ssjs, sales-cloud

I am trying to delete multiple records using REST Api.

```
    var contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = [("Bearer "+sessionId)];

    var allRecords = DataExtension.Init("MyDataExtension").Rows.Retrieve();
    for (var i=0; i < allRecords.length; i++){
          var ContactId = allRecords[i].ContactId;
          var Url = ('https://blablabla.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/' + ContactId);

          var result = HTTP.Delete(Url, contentType, headerNames, headerValues);
        }
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: Delete.

What is wrong with this ssjs code? or is there any other way to do this?

EDIT

Below is my edited code. This returns error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
var contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = [("Bearer "+sessionId)];

var allRecords = DataExtension.Init("MyDataExtension").Rows.Retrieve();

var url = 'https://blablabla.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/composite';
var payload = { "compositeRequest": [] };

for(var i = 0; i < allRecords.length; i++) {
//var contact = Stringify(allRecords[i].ContactId);
payload.compositeRequest.push(
    { "method": "DELETE",
    "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/"+allRecords[i].ContactId   //allRecords[i].ContactId OR var contact?
    });
if(payload.compositeRequest.length == 25 || i == allRecords.length - 1) {
    var response = HTTP.Post(url, "application/json", Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);  // JSON.Stringify OR Stringify?
    log.Rows.Add({Log: "response: " + response});
    payload.compositeRequest = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP.Delete is not a valid method name. You only have the options for GET and POST. Instead, use the [POST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpPost.htm) method and use the [composite request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) resource. As a bonus, you can delete up to 25 records at once this way.

---

```
var url = 'https://blablabla.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/composite';
var payload = { "compositeRequest": [] };
for(var i = 0; i < allRecords.length; i++) {
  payload.compositeRequest.push(
    { "method": "DELETE", 
      "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/"+allRecords[i].ContactId 
    });
  if(payload.compositeRequest.length == 25 || i == allRecords.length - 1) {
    var response = HTTP.Post(url, "application/json", Platform.Function.Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
    payload.compositeRequest = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful. However, now I am getting a different error:  `"Object expected: stringify"`

Comment: @Stuart Try `Stringify` instead of `Platform.Function.Stringify`? Or... Did you make sure to use a capital S instead of lowercase s?

Comment: I edited my post above. When I log the url variable in the loop, i see it still ends with "....services/data/v42.0/composite". It should change to "....services/data/v42.0/contactId + delete request, right? If that makes sense..  Thanks.

Comment: @Stuart No, it's a composite resource endpoint. It allows you to POST multiple requests at once. Please feel free to check the link in the answer, it describes how this feature works.

Comment: Because of your answer, I read a lot of documentation about this feature. I learned a lot from it, but unfortunately I cant get it to work. The closest I got was getting error:  `"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame"`. I abandoned REST for this problem and  found a solution using SOAP. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.